# Overwrite row values where string is longer than 2 characters

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
Column A    Column B
6   DA
1   ZX
2   DS
4   DSSS
1   FA
```

I'd like to select rows where the values in column B are longer than 2 and make them blank. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
df.loc[df['Column B'].str.len() > 2, 'Column B'] = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick list comprehension:

```
l = [len(a)>2 for a in df['Column B']]
df['Column B'] = np.where(l, '', df['Column B'])
```

Output:

```
   Column A Column B
0         6       DA
1         1       ZX
2         2       DS
3         4         
4         1       FA
```